# Close one JFrame without closing another?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to display two (or more) *JFrames* at the same time.
When I close one of them (use the default close button), the other frames should still be visible.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you do **not** want your application to terminate when a `JFrame` is closed, use

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
```

instead of

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29):

- `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` (defined in WindowConstants): Don't do anything; require the program to handle the operation in the windowClosing method of a registered WindowListener object.
- `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
- `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and dispose the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
- `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.

---

This was my answer before the question was clarified, might still be useful:

You can use `setVisible(false)` on your `JFrame` if you want to display the same frame again.
Otherwise call `dispose()` to [remove all of the native screen resources](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29).

Comment: thanks,but i close the window with the close-button at the upper-right corner. It doesn't use setVisible(false) definitely and must stop the thread.

Comment: I think i must override some mothed, i don't know which mothed but i believe it isn't the closing mothed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to achieve, could you please edit your question and add some information about what you try to do and what does not work?

Comment: calling DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE before init() worked for me.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Does it help you ?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TwoJFrames {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nb = 4;
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            nb = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }

        final int frameCount = nb;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame number " + i);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    p.add(new JLabel("Click on the corner to close..."), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.setContentPane(p);
                    frame.setSize(200, 200);
                    frame.setLocation(100 + 20 * i, 100 + 20 * i);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Dint worked for me . Then on design view from properties i have set defaultCloseOperation to Dispose and finally it work.