# Close/Exit child frame without closing parent frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, exit

I have created a second Frame in another frame.
I noticed that when I close the second frame, the first one closes too.

How can i avoid that?
I would like the first frame to remain as it is and without closing.

My code for the second frame is:

```
 JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);       
 frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //when it closes the first frame closes too
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close one JFrame without closing another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944446/close-one-jframe-without-closing-another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved**

I read the following answer [Close one JFrame without closing another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944446/close-one-jframe-without-closing-another) and i found the answer

- I **removed**

  ```
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  ```
- and I **added** the following

  ```
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  ```

Comment: An aaplication should only has a single JFrame. For child windows you should use a JDialog. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice