# How to close the Jframe without closing other frames Netbeans

Tags: java, swing

So when I click on X button the whole program closes but i only want to close the frame which I want to close i am using Net beans.
I can't figure it out Google says to add closing event but as i see the X button is already there. What to do?

Comment: What is your code? Or it's all the behavior generated by Net Beans?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Netbeans.

Comment: I am creating a program for inventory management where i have 3-4 frames but when i close any other frame the main frame also closes.

Comment: Debugging your code is pretty difficult when we don't have your code...

Comment: The code itself generated by netbeans so i just want to close a single frame not the program what to do?

Comment: I've never used Netbeans before but does that IDE seriously not give you an option to edit the generated code?

Comment: You most certainly _can_ edit the code generated by it's Gui builder.

Comment: I don't know i just want to close the current frame not the whole program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close one JFrame without closing another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944446/close-one-jframe-without-closing-another)

Comment: Again, the proper solution is to use a JDialog. Why fight this?

Answer (score 3):

> I am creating a program for inventory management where i have 3-4 frames

An application should only have a single JFrame.

If you need child windows then use a `JDialog`. When you close a dialog is does not close the main JFrame.

However, for information regarding a JFrame check out the `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)` method. The default is to "hide" the frame. So if your application is exiting then that means you are probably using the `System.exit(...)` method somewhere in your code which you should not be doing.

Comment: I have already created frames the program is almost done just 2 things are left closing other frame without closing the program and one other thing.

Comment: I am not using System.exit anywhere. I am using the X button on the frame which was already there not programmed by me.

Comment: @user3551620, so a JDialog is the same as a JFrame except for the class name. It will take a minute to change the code. There is no time like the present to learn how to design an application properly. This is a small change.

Comment: Umm but i want to close the frame not the program.

Comment: @user3551620, `I am not using System.exit anywhere`, did you read the API for the method I mentioned? Does the generated code use that method? `Umm but i want to close the frame not the program` - which is why you should use a JDialog and NOT a JFrame. The default behaviour is to close the dialog when you click on the "X" button.

Answer (score 1):

Found in the properties of the Jframe which i want to close
defaultCloseOperation was set to EXIT_ON_CLOSE i set it to Dispose.

Comment: As I suggested in my answer. This is still not the proper solution. If you don't believe me then check out: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) for more information.

Comment: @camickr I know its not the proper way to it but thanks anyway :)