# Dispose method to close a JFrame (but not the entire program) from a separate class in NetBeans is not working. Why?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have three classes I am working with here. The first is an admin page where the user can select to either add, update or delete an employee on the system via a drop down box. When the user selects one of the three options from the combo box, a JFrame (employees) comes up with the necessary fields to perform their task and the admin frame will still be displayed behind it. On this frame there is a "Cancel" button. When they click the cancel button only this frame must close but keep the admin frame open still. The button is generated from a separate class (empClass) to be displayed on the employee frame. My problem now is I am struggling to get the button to dispose of the employee frame, but out of the several ways of trying this it cannot work. One way produced an error each time I ran the application, another method caused the application to crash/freeze whenever I try select an option to perform on the employee frame and the code I have currently implemented performs no action at all. I think the problem is a an issue with communicating with the forms but I am not entirely sure. Please help as I have been struggling with this for hours and the internet is providing absolutely nothing useful. Most resources refer to the `dispose()` method which I have tried in various ways but all the ways I have tried do not work, crash the application or cause errors to occur. Even the other questions similar to this on here have not helped me out at all.

I have tried calling the button from the employee frame to try and link the function to the "Cancel" button. Here is the code I have implemented in the empClass:

```
public void disposeof()
    {

        employees empp = new employees();
        empp.dispose();
    }

private void cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        disposeof();
    }
```

Here is the employee coding:

```
public class employees extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    empClass ec = new empClass();
    adminPage ap = new adminPage();

    public employees() {
        initComponents();
      getContentPane().add(ec.getpanel());
       this.add(ec.getpanel());
       this.add(ec.lbltitle);
       this.add(ec.cancel);
       this.add(ec.bfunction);
       this.add(ec.empList); 
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close one JFrame without closing another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944446/close-one-jframe-without-closing-another)

Comment: did you add `setDefaultCloseOperation(employees.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`? or tried `setVisible(flase)`

Comment: then you should set all properties of jframe by making an object of employees and then pass this employees object through the method `disposeof` and then call `dispose()` by passed object OR dispose it by keyword `this`

Comment: I am unable to understand this part `empClass ec = new empClass();
    adminPage ap = new adminPage();`. what is `empClass` and `adminPage`.Trust me there is nothing wrong with `JFrame` , problem is in your OOP implementation.

Comment: The `adminPage` is a Swing Frame where the user will access the employees Frame. `empClass` is the java class where the objects such as buttons and labels etc. are created to be displayed on the employees frame. I just deleted the `adminPage ap = new adminPage();` as that was from a previous attempt I tried that is no longer relevant. The `employees ec = new employees();` is what we used to get the objects from the `empClass` to display on the employees Frame.

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't provide the code of your `JFrame` so I guess problem is in the code of your `JFrame`. You might be setting `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame .EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` for your employee class as it is static property so it will close all JFrames. You should set it `setDefaultCloseOperation(employees.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` OR `setDefaultCloseOperation(employees.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`.
 And after that while triggering your event you can call `empp.dispose();` OR `setVisible(flase)`.

Comment: I just tried that in this manner:

`public void disposeof()
    {
        employees empp = new employees();
        empp.setDefaultCloseOperation(employees.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        empp.dispose();
    }

private void cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        disposeof();        
    }`

It still is not working. Did I implement it in the correct way?

Comment: so is it still not working? have you tried `setVisible(false)`?

Comment: `setVisible(false)` also isn't working :(

But is what I've done right? Should I maybe edit my question and include ALL the coding in in case it's something elsewhere in the coding causing the problem that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I included the employees coding in an edit on the question just now

Comment: and your `AdminJframe` is another class extended by JFrame? it should be? isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82631/discussion-between-freak-and-osiris93).

Answer (score 1):

First of all only use one JFrame and use JDialogs for the underlying other windows you may want to see appearing. On JDialog, use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is to hide the frame using `setVisible(false)`.