# Java Swing - Why is my first window not disposing/closing?

Tags: java, swing

So I'm creating an application. I want main to initialize a login window, which I've done. And for now I want the login window to close whenever I click on the button, and when it closes, a new window (called MainWindow) opens with different buttons/info/text.

All these classes are separate, but in the same package.

**The problem is:** The main window opens when I click login, however the login window doesn't terminate/close.

**My main method, from which I call the login window:**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    // Display Login Window
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new LoginWindow();
            LoginWindow.createAndShowLoginGUI();
        });
    }
}
```

**My login window class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LoginWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public void prepareLoginGUI() {

        // Frame with GridBagLayout
        JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame("Login Window");
        loginFrame.setSize(1200, 800);
        loginFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        // Button for logging in, with respective GridBagConstraint
        // setFocusable is set to false to take out the border around the text
        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);
        loginButton.setActionCommand("Open");
        GridBagConstraints lButtonC = new GridBagConstraints();
        loginButton.setFocusable(false);


        // Username text-field and JLabel with respective GridBagConstraints
        JTextField tfUsername = new JTextField(15);
        GridBagConstraints tfUserC = new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel txtUser = new JLabel("Username: ");
        GridBagConstraints txtUserC = new GridBagConstraints();


        // Password text-field and JLabel with respective GridBagConstraints
        JPasswordField tfPassword = new JPasswordField(15);
        GridBagConstraints tfPassC = new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel txtPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
        GridBagConstraints txtPassC = new GridBagConstraints();


        // Add all components to the JFrame
        // Making sure to add the text before the text-fields
        loginFrame.add(txtUser, txtUserC);
        loginFrame.add(tfUsername, tfUserC);
        loginFrame.add(txtPassword, txtPassC);
        loginFrame.add(tfPassword, tfPassC);
        loginFrame.add(loginButton, lButtonC);

        // Show and set close parameters
        loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loginFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Instructions for when the login button is clicked
    // Close this window, if button == open, which it does
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
        if (cmd.equals("Open")) {
            this.dispose();
            this.setVisible(false);
            new MainWindow();
            MainWindow.createAndShowMainWGUI();
        }
    }

    // Callable from Main class
    public static void createAndShowLoginGUI() {
        LoginWindow loginW = new LoginWindow();
        loginW.prepareLoginGUI();

    }

}
```

**My Main Window Class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public void prepareMainWGUI(){
        // Frame with GridBagLayout
        JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame("Main Window");
        loginFrame.setSize(1200, 800);
        loginFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        // Username text-field and JLabel with respective GridBagConstraints
        JLabel txtUser = new JLabel("It worked!");
        GridBagConstraints txtUserC = new GridBagConstraints();

        loginFrame.add(txtUser, txtUserC);

        loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        loginFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Callable from Main class
    public static void createAndShowMainWGUI() {
        MainWindow mainWind = new MainWindow();
        mainWind.prepareMainWGUI();
    }

}
```

If you use this code, when the main window opens, the login window will be right behind it.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for the link. I'm wondering how would I change the display of the frame then? Should I use panels for each display i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use when pressing button

```
System.exit(0);
```

This will terminate your application. To close one window use(if you have open multiple windows) without affecting to others,

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
```

Then, to open new one,

```
new frameName().setvisible(true);
```

Example:

```
JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");

closeButton .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        this.dispose();//current(close only this) frame
        new frameName().setvisible(true);
    }
});
```

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944446/close-one-jframe-without-closing-another).

**UPDATE:**

In below line you have `extends JFrame` but you didnot use it.

```
public class LoginWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

Rather than that you have create new object from `JFrame`

```
JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame("Login Window");
```

All the component you are adding to the `loginFrame`. But when `actionPerformed` trying to `this.dispose()`, since you are not using extended `JFrame` nothing will happen.

**Solution:**

Declare your `JFrame` as a instance variable:

```
public class LoginWindow implements ActionListener {
    JFrame loginFrame;
    public void prepareLoginGUI() {
```

Then change,

```
this.dispose();
```

To:

```
loginFrame.dispose();
```

In this `this.dispose();` call to the extended `JFrame`, no effect for your `JFrame` object(`loginForm`).

And one last thing, make sure to remove `extends JFrame`. Because you are not doing anything with extended `JFrame`. Read this [post about extended `JFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867148/why-do-we-need-to-extend-jframe-in-a-swing-application).

Comment: hmm, weird I've done this exact same thing. But when I do it within the prepareMainWGUI method rather than overriding it, it works. Why is this?

Comment: Few things have to point. wait a minute I will update the answer

Comment: @Theo take a look at **UPDATE** section

Comment: @Theo read this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867148/why-do-we-need-to-extend-jframe-in-a-swing-application