# Closing one jframe all remaining opening jframe will close.

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have made a program in which three jframe is exist. But the problem is that when I close one jframe all the remaining opening jframe is also closed. Please help me.

Comment: [First search on google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944446/close-one-jframe-without-closing-another). Try to search before asking.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want your application to terminate when a JFrame is closed, use

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be specific need for your project to create 3 JFrames but it is a good GUI making practice, to create only a single JFrame.
For additional windows, which you want to open from parent JFrame, you can easily use JDialogs which offers more functionalities over opening a new child JFrame. :-)

Comment: This would have made a great comment, but is not an answer.

Comment: Yes for sure Andrew. Thanks for the point. :-)

Comment: Andrew I think you are the right person to ask. Can u please help me with my question "Arial Unicode MS Not Working With Jtree"??

Answer (score -1):

You can Use jframe.dispose() function or if you use NetBeans then you find a option in project properties the defaultCloseOperation tab then select Dispose from drop Down Menu