# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog Query?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

This is the Scenario.

I have Code which intiates a Alram when an error is encountered.

```
AudioAlarm t = new AudioAlarm(song);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Awake");
    t.start();
    setRunnung(true);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alarm ...", "Alarm", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    AudioAlarm.setLoop(false);
    System.out.println("Alarm Acknowledged ...");
```

I would like to re-design this logic in this manner,

If the Alarm is unacknowledged by the user over a period of time say 2 min, it turn off and message msg dialog should disappear.

How can I Obtain this?

I am able to Stop the Alram, but unable to dispose the dialog without the user pressing "OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you should:

- Create a `JOptionPane` instance using one of its constructors
- Call `createDialog` on this option pane to get a dialog containing this option pane
- Use a `javax.swing.Timer` instance in order to fire an action event after 2 minutes
- add an action listener to this timer which would close the dialog containing the option pane
- show the dialog containing the option pane.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if what you are after can be done, but can't you instead replicate the JOptionPane as a JFrame and dispose of that one? You can find how to close a JFrame on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe) Previous SO Post:

> If you want the GUI to behave as if
>   you clicked the "X" then you need to
>   dispatch a windowClosing Event to the
>   Window. The "ExitAction" from [Closing
>   An Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) allows you to add this
>   functionality to a menu item or any
>   component that uses Actions easily.