# How to actually close a Window in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, frame, dispose

I need to close a `JFrame` window so that the next call to access it catches `NullPointerException`.I tried `frame.dispose()` but, it did not work, I am getting back that window whenever I try `frame.setVisible(true)`. How can I do that?

Comment: Check this link out for some reference material: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe

Comment: The code is too big to post here.

Comment: *"I need to close a JFrame window so that the next call to access it"*  There should only be one `JFrame` and it should be visible form application start to finish (unless the user minimizes it or brings other apps. in front of it).  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you re-evaluate your program logic as it seems strange that you would rather see a `NullPointerException` instead of just *knowing* your code won't try and make visible a frame that should be dead.

Regardless, you can simply set your `JFrame` instance to `null` to ensure it cannot be made visible again. That will certainly give you the exception you desire.

*Remember that a `NullPointerException` should be reserved for indicating programming errors, typically the violation of an API contract. Don't use them to control program flow, nor design a program that is knowingly going to trigger them.*

Comment: Actually, I have already wrote a large program (with some catch of `NullPointerException`'s), if I could do that then I will not need to modify my code a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Frame.dispose() or setVisible(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user pressed the "X-button"? In that case use

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: That would end the application.  Use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.dispose();
frame = null;
```