# Closing parent element of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, swingutilities

Is it possible to close parent element of a component .. probably a `JFrame`/`JInternalFrame` from a JPanel? if yes how it can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help you:

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(panel).dispose();
```

or

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(panel).setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe)

```
public class CustomPanel extends JPanel {

  private JFrame parent; //Need to pass this reference somehow, constructor or otherwise

  public void closeJFrame() {
    WindowEvent winEvent = new WindowEvent(parent, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winEvent );
  }
}
```