# How to close a JFrame window when user clicks on a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, multiple-instances, billing

My program is about a supermarket. I have created a JButton called b1 in the delivery() method. I want the JFrame window to close when the user presses the button b1. But unfortunately i do not know how to do that. Please help. Below is the delivery() method of my program:

```
public static void delivery()
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Name");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(600,200);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocation(700,450);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    final JLabel l = new JLabel("Enter your name: ");

    final JTextField jt = new JTextField(20);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Ok");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            input = jt.getText();
        }
    });

    p.add(b1);
    p.add(l);
    p.add(jt);
    f.add(p);

    String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your address in one single line:");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The ordered stuff will be delivered to " +input+ " who lives in: " +b , "Delivery" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for shopping at Paradise 24/7. Hope to see you again." , "Shopping Done!" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply call `f.dispose()` so you can close the JFrame

Answer (score 7):

- use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead of [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for popup window
- with [setModal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), [ModalityTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) to prevent `Mouse` and `Keyboard` events outside `JDialog` if is required
- create only one istance of `JDialog` as local variable, [setDefaultCloseOperations(HIDE_ON_CLOSE)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29), then you'll use [setVisible(true/false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) for whole apllication life cycle

Comment: +1..... @user2536634 , Also have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: +1 -- this is the correct answer for showing and closing dependent windows.

Answer (score 2):

setVisible() should do the trick for ya

```
    public static void delivery()
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Name");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(600,200);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocation(700,450);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    final JLabel l = new JLabel("Enter your name: ");
    final JTextField jt = new JTextField(20);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Ok");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            input = jt.getText();
            f.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    p.add(b1);
    p.add(l);
    p.add(jt);
    f.add(p);
    String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your address in one single line:");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The ordered stuff will be delivered to " +input+ " who lives in: " +b , "Delivery" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for shopping at Paradise 24/7. Hope to see you again." , "Shopping Done!" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```