# When a JFrame is Closed

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a `JFrame` and I would like to know when the close button is clicked for that `JFrame`. When the `JFrame` is closed my whole project does not close so I want to be able to tell when the user closes that one Frame.

I've tried using methods like as **!f.isShowing** and **!m.f.isActive()** but when I close the Frame, what I want to happen doesn't.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe?rq=1

Comment: I don't want to close it, I want to know when the user closes it.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you simply have a problem with the run not ending when the frame closes, or do you want to do something when the frame closes? Because both are mentioned in your question.

Comment: I have to wonder if this isn't really an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise and if what you really want is to use a modal JDialog. If you tell us more of the background story, we may be able to give you a much better answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to do anything special when the frame closes, you can use `setDefaultCloseOperation` to change the way a `JFrame`

```
EXIT_ON_CLOSE
```

> The exit application default window close operation. If a window has
>   this set as the close operation and is closed in an applet, a
>   SecurityException may be thrown. It is recommended you only use this
>   in an application.

```
HIDE_ON_CLOSE
```

> The hide-window default window close operation

```
DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
```

> The dispose-window default window close operation. Note: When the last
>   displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed
>   of, the VM may terminate. See AWT Threading Issues for more
>   information.

Comment: 1+, but I'm guessing that he really wants a modal JDialog, since he wants to know when the window is closed and does not want the app to close. But til he tells more, who knows?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's kinda of what I thought, hence the reason for the opening statement

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,...) ...) {
            // ...
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @dic19 Rubbish, System.exit instructs the JVM to terminate in controlled and known manner and won't be terminated until all non-daemon threads are also terminated.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was wrong my entirely java life I guess :P

Comment: @dic19 I know the feeling ;)

Comment: Sorry @pospeq I've revoked my unnecessary/incorrect downvote.

Answer (score 0):

> when the `JFrame` is closed my whole project does not close...

A common cause of this is that when you declare a JFrame you should call this method of JFrame to make it close when you press the 'x' button:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```