# Error while Exiting Jframe window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have one window of class `Jframe` and it contains one button. On Clicking that button the second window of class `Jframe` is opened. On Clicking the close or the exit button of second window then the first window is also closed along with second window.
Why is this happening?

below is my code : 
// this is my first file

```
class Frame1 extends JFrame
{
Frame1()
{
        super("hello this is window 1");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton btn = new JButton("open second window");
       btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("button clicked");
                Frame2 obj2 = new Frame2();
        }
    });
    add(btn);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
        Frame1 obj = new Frame1();
}
}

// this is my second file
class Frame2 extends JFrame
{
Frame2()
{
        super("hello this is window 2");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? Show us.

Comment: what is the problem, what is the Error? and post your code please to get help.

Comment: when i click on exit button of one window then second window is also exited with one window. i don't have the code for exiting. it is automatically done.

Comment: i don't the reason why this is happening ?

Comment: @SarthakShah: Without seeing the code that produces the problem, it is very hard to try and determine what the problem is. Please post the code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add window listener in the second frame, then just dispose it, something like:

```
frame2.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        frame2.dispose();
    }
});

OR

frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

But note that its not a good practices to use multiple `JFrame's` in you're application, use one `JFrame` and multiple `Dialogs`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the default close event (which quits the program) and then close that one JFrame explicitly.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Some links that might help:

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235283/2407870

Answer (score 1):

Change the Value of the setDefaultCloseOperation() parameter to JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE to prevent the second Frame from closing the First Frame

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your `Frame2` class

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then add this to the same line:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```