# How to close JFrame without using default methods?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating a frame using NetBeans IDE, by default the frame is closed.  I modified the default behaviour such as `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`.  I want to close manually.

How to close `JFrame` without using default methods?

Here is my code:

```
public class FrameClose extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public FrameClose() {

      initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameClose.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameClose.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameClose.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameClose.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FrameClose().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: See [How to Write Window Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).

Comment: What do you mean you want to close manually

Comment: Yep, the question is not very clear at all. What are "default methods" which you want to avoid? What do you mean by "close manually"? Also, since you are learning Swing I strongly suggest that you not use a windows builder utility but instead code by hand using the Swing tutorials as a guide until you learn the library.

Comment: See [How to programmatically close a JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1235994/878469).

Comment: Send `WINDOW_CLOSING`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513).

Answer (score 0):

you can use dispose() method on frame object, 
for ex:

```
JFrame frame  = new JFrame();
frame.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a WindowListener

```
addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) { }
});
```

Use this instead of calling `setDefaultCloseOperation()` and then just use which ever method works best for what you want to do.

Or if you want to close the frame in code use `setVisible(false);` to hide the Frame or use `dispose()` to get rid of the entire frame