# close JFrame on button click

Tags: java, swing, button

I am making a menu system. I have run into a problem.. Whenever I press the button to move to the next menu, the old JFrame stays open behind the new one. Code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainMenu frame = new MainMenu();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainMenu() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start Game");
    btnStart.setBounds(154, 82, 126, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnStart);

    JLabel lblBattleKoalas = new JLabel("Battle Koalas");
    lblBattleKoalas.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 35));
    lblBattleKoalas.setBounds(121, 11, 219, 48);
    contentPane.add(lblBattleKoalas);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Player Menu");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(154, 116, 126, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Game.main(null);

        }
    });
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new DispPlayer());
}

static class DispPlayer implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PlayerMenu.main(null);
        //Close Current Frame Here
    }

}
```

}
How would I get the MainMenu to close and the PlayerMenu to open up? Any help would be great!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe

Comment: 1) For many components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0):

The method `setVisile(boolean b)` isn't used only to make frames appear, you can also use it to make them disapear. For example, if frame is your MainMenu object, you might want to call `frame.setVisible(false);` when someone presses the button you want them to.

So.. Lets consider your button is `btn`, that your first menu was `oldMenu` and the menu you'd like to display is `newMenu`.
I believe you could write:

```
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        oldMenu.setVisible(false);
        //don't forget to create the new menu
        newMenu.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I needed to do `MainMenu.this.dispose();` to access the JFrame