# Using JMenu or JMenuItem, my Exit button does not work

Tags: java

I am using the following code, I tried to implement an Exit button, but it does nothing when it is pressed.

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
setJMenuBar( menuBar );
JMenuItem menuClose = new JMenu( "Exit" );
menuClose.setToolTipText("Exit application");

menuClose.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
        System.exit(0);
    }
});

menuBar.add( menuClose );
```

Ideas?

Comment: You should probably create a `JMenu`, then create a `JMenuItem` and add it to the `JMenu`.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably create a `JMenu`, then create a `JMenuItem` and add it to the `JMenu`.

So, your code would look like :

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
setJMenuBar( menuBar );
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Exit");
JMenuItem menuClose = new JMenuItem( "Exit application" );
menuClose.setToolTipText("Exit application");
menu.add(menuClose);
menuBar.add(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
setVisible(false);
dispose();
```

as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235321/2833217

Comment: This assumes that the frame's `defaultCloseOpertation` is set to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`