# Java GUI - JButton opens another frame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

i'm having trouble to get the 2nd frame to display the GUI Components. i've opened the frame using the `JButton` from the 1st frame.

Here's the screen shot

This is the first frame - ClientModule.java
[image]

2nd frame - ClientMenu.java
[image]

Here's the codes i've tried

**ClientModule.java**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ClientModule extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel titleLbl, userLbl, passLbl, hostLbl, portLbl, ipLbl;
    private JTextField userTxt, hostTxt, portTxt, ipTxt;
    private JPasswordField passTxt;
    private JButton loginBtn;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ClientModule().run();
    }

    public ClientModule()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("DMS(Drawing Message System)");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        titleLbl = new JLabel("LogIn to Drawing Message System(DMS)");
        titleLbl.setFont(new Font("Rockwell Condensed",Font.BOLD,28));      
        userLbl = new JLabel("Username:");
        passLbl = new JLabel("Password:");
        hostLbl = new JLabel("Hostname:");
        portLbl = new JLabel("Port No.:");
        ipLbl = new JLabel("IP Address:");

        userTxt = new JTextField();
        userTxt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

        passTxt = new JPasswordField();
        passTxt.setEchoChar('*');
        passTxt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

        portTxt = new JTextField();
        portTxt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

        ipTxt = new JTextField();
        ipTxt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

        hostTxt = new JTextField();
        hostTxt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

        loginBtn = new JButton("Login!");
        loginBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,30));
        loginBtn.addActionListener(new LoginBtnListener());


        panel.add(titleLbl);
        panel.add(userLbl);
        panel.add(userTxt);
        panel.add(passLbl);
        panel.add(passTxt);
        panel.add(hostLbl);
        panel.add(hostTxt);
        panel.add(portLbl);
        panel.add(portTxt);
        panel.add(ipLbl);
        panel.add(ipTxt);
        panel.add(loginBtn);

        frame.add(panel);

    }

    private class LoginBtnListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
        {
            //thinking this frame will close after ClientMenu's frame is open
            ClientModule client = new ClientModule();
            client.setVisible(false);

            ClientMenu menu = new ClientMenu();
            menu.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**ClientMenu.java**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClientMenu extends JFrame{

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel titleLbl;
    JButton sendBtn,receiveBtn,logoutBtn;

    public ClientMenu()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Drawing Message System(DMS)");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

        titleLbl = new JLabel("Main Menu");
        titleLbl.setFont(new Font("Rockwell Condensed",Font.BOLD,28));

        sendBtn = new JButton("Send a Drawing");
        sendBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

        receiveBtn = new JButton("Receive a Drawing");
        receiveBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

        logoutBtn = new JButton("Logout");
        logoutBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
        logoutBtn.addActionListener(new LogoutBtnListener());

        panel.add(titleLbl);
        panel.add(sendBtn);
        panel.add(receiveBtn);
        panel.add(logoutBtn);

        frame.add(panel);
    }

    private class LogoutBtnListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
        {
            ClientModule client = new ClientModule();
            client.setVisible(true);

            ClientMenu menu = new ClientMenu();
            menu.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ClientMenu().run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if i'm missing something, or coded something wrong, or something else. I've already searched and tried.. 
any help and understanding is appreciated (:

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What would happen if you call `run()` from the constructor of your 2nd frame?

Comment: ahh,,sorry.. if i click the button in ClientModule class, it should open the 2nd frame from ClientMenu class. But the Gui components are not shown in the 2nd frame..

Comment: and.. i'm not sure how to make the 1st frame(ClientModule) to be closed automatically after 2nd frame is opened..

Comment: @npinti the `run( )` method should display the frame which has the panel and the components

Comment: Did you tried to directly run your 2nd frame to see if components are displayed ?

Comment: Your code is a whole mess and you clearly do not understand how instantiation works in Java. You can try to add `menu.run()` to your listener.

Comment: To programmatically close a JFrame, refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe)

Comment: @Kapcash yeah did directly run and the components are shown.

Comment: @MuratK. the `menu.run()` works! thanks :D

Comment: `ClientModule client = new ClientModule();` this makes no sense in you buttons `ActionListener`, you should just use the instance of `ClientModule` which already have.  Your `ClientMenu` class extends from `JFrame` BUT creates it's own instance of `JFrame` internally, which is causing no end of confusion and problems

Comment: Take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) and instead may be use a `CardLayout` or dialog.  See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: I'd discourage you from extending directly from `JFrame` and I'm not sure why you need to implement `Runnable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the second frame displayed (including its contents) by adding a call to the `run()` method:

```
        ClientMenu menu = new ClientMenu();
        menu.setVisible(true);  
        menu.run();
```

That being said, there are quite some problems with your code:

1. You have a `main` method in each of your classes. You should have **only 1** main method per application. Since `ClientModule` seems to be the first Frame you want to have opened, your might want to keep the main method there and remove the one in the other class.
2. You have a `run()` method in each class. Personally, I tend to avoid naming methods like this, since it might cause confusion with the `run()` method which needs to be overridden when dealing with threads. You are clearly attempting to do some multi threading in your `ClientModule`, but will not work. Please look into [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) concurrency tutorial to better understand threads. You should also understand that **you should never** call `run()` yourself. The tutorial should make that clear.
3. Swing applications are started a little bit differently that other applications. Please refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) tutorial for more information.
4. You have both your classes `extend` JFrame but then, provide your own. This results in other JFrames being created, which is what happened in my case (I get 2 JFrames per instantiation). If you want your class to behave like a JFrame, consider extending it, if you want to use a JFrame, then compose your class of one, not both (at least not in this case).
5. Lastly, to get rid of the previous JFrame you *could* call `dispose()` on the it. That being said, the approach usually is to use the [`Card Layout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#card). This would allow you to have 1 frame with multiple content.

Sorry for the long post, but please consider re factoring as per the above prior to continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setVisible property to 'true' or 'false'.