# How to close window (Java Swing) after run?

Tags: java, swing

I have standard Swing GUI class:

```
public class ElevatorGUI extends JFrame implements Observer {
private JButton button2;
private JTextArea textArea2;
private JSeparator separator2;
private JLabel label4;
private JLabel label5;
private JLabel label6;
```

with init

```
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
GroupLayout contentPaneLayout = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(contentPaneLayout);
    contentPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
```

... etc.
So we can to close this GUI by standard way:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

but how to do the same thing from method?
For example:

```
public void update() {
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [How to programmatically close a JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe):

> `frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`

When the class extends `JFrame`, do this instead:

> `this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`

When this is executed the JFrame will be closed exactly as if the user pressed the "x" button.

Comment: but I haven't any frame in my class/ I tryed : this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)); But nothing exit(

Comment: @Spacemaster see edit, when the class extends `JFrame`

Comment: (1+) `but I haven't any frame in my class` - sure you do. Your class extends JFrame. Understand the concept of the answer, and modify as required.

Comment: ) I know that it extends JFrame. But how to apply your trick to my class?)

Comment: this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)); I did it. But nothing happened

Comment: Maybe it happens necause my window visibility is false?

Comment: Its ok. Simply my 2nd class isnt started .. I saw it in debugger. Thx.