# how to remove all frames after log out

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm using Java . I have 25 frames 
and they are opening randomly. When I click on Log out the objective is visible and invisible all frames will be closed 
and Log out will redirect to Log in Frame.

I'm using Java JDBC and NETBEANS IDE.

Comment: You're using 25 JFrames?!? Swing Convention only allows for one instance of a JFrame at a time.

Comment: Where can I find these swing conventions, @andrewdleach?

Comment: Just type in Java Swing Tutorial into the google search bar... oracle has a good one, tutorials point does too, vogella, there is of course always Stack Overflow...

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When each frame is created, add it to a List of some sort and when the user clicks Log Out, iterate through the List and on each frame call

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe).

After that just create the Log In frame again.