# Java Swing and Java Fx: Dispose method on Frame doesnt actually kill the window

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am calling  dispose method and also setting setDefaultCloseOperation for the frame.

However, after dispose being called upon, i checked with Dialog.getallwindows() the frame is not actually killed. Is there any alternative way to dispose frame

Comment: why would you want to do it? any gain by doing so? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe

Comment: i have a feeling my desktop client is getting slow with number of increasing frames. Also i i iterate over Dialog.getallwindows it takes more time

Comment: how many frames are you talking of? normally it is enough to dispose any frame as the GC will clear it up afterwards. if you want to force the GC to run, call `System.gc();`

Comment: 1000 frames are running smoothly and at 10k its starting to lag a bit. yet no gui should ever extend way more than 10-20 frames at a time and this should not be a problem unless you work on a toaster

Comment: But if i am iterating over dialog.getwindows  before creating a new frame it takes time

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.