# Closing JFrames through button

Tags: swing

I have used many methods like `hide();`,  `setvisibility` and all. But they are not working. 
How can I close it dynamically by clicking on another frame button?

I have used all things which are below on button but not working:

```
 rest1.Disp ds = new rest1.Disp();
            ds.setVisible(true);

            rest.Cashier c = new rest.Cashier();
            c.hide();
            c.setVisible(false);
               c.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
              c.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             c.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Step 1.

You should call the [`setDefaultCloseOperation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-) during initialization of your JFrame. This tells the system how it should respond when the 'X' (close) button of your JFrame is clicked.

It has an integer parameter that can take 4 possible values:

> - DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Don't do
>     anything; require the program to handle the operation in the
>     windowClosing method of a registered WindowListener object.
> - HIDE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide the
>     frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
> - DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and
>     dispose the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener
>     objects.
> - EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application
>     using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.

It sounds like `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is what you are looking for - it will hide and dispose the JFrame on which the 'X' button was clicked.

So, in the initialization of your JFrame, call

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Further reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

#### Step 2.

When you have your JFrame set up to be disposed on closing, you can also close it programmatically. You can use

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235994/812149).
What happens then is that `dispatchEvent` will send the WINDOW_CLOSING event to the frame. The system knows it should dispose the frame, because you told it to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

So, you should put that command in the ActionListener for the button that you use to close the frame:

```
someButton.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener( )
    {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
       {
           frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
       }
    }
 );
```

Together, these two things accomplish that your frame is closed from a button other than the normal 'X' closing button.

Comment: I want to close dynamically by clicking on another frame button

Comment: @Ansh You want to programmatically close it from _another_ frame, or from a custom button? Then you need to send a WindowClosingEvent to the frame you intend to close. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235994/812149): `frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`