# How to close JFrame once boolean is true?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want my `JFrame` program to close as soon as a boolean **`isDead`** is true.

How do I do this?

```
if (isDead) {
    // Close the program
}
```

---

```
JFrame obj = new JFrame();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically close a JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe)

Answer (score 1):

just use `frame.setActive(false)` (this will just hide the frame and if you want to close the whole program)

Answer (score 0):

```
setVisible(false); 
dispose();
```